# How to create 2 dimensional List

Tags: java, list, multidimensional-array, arraylist

This is my situation. I have 8 `zone`s. Consider them as rooms in a building. each `zone` got number of cameras which i don't know. for an example, zone1 might have 6 cams, zone2 might have 3 cams etc. now i need to track these `camera` objects which is inside these zones. i thought of adding 2 dimensional list because them the first dimension can contain the `zone` while the second dimension can contain the `camera`. how can i do this?

anyway, if you feel there is a better way, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Zone` and `Camera` are itself class then You could use `HashMap` as follows:

```
Map<Zone,ArrayList<Camera>> map = new HashMap<Zone,ArrayList<Camera>>();
ArrayList<Camera> list1 = new ArrayList<Camera>();
list1.add(camera1);list1.add(camera2);
map.put(zone1,list1);
ArrayList<Camera> list2 = new ArrayList<Camera>();
 list2.add(camera1);list2.add(camera2);list2.add(camera3);
map.put(zone2,list2);
....
...
```

Where camera1,camera2 ..so on are objects of `Camera`. And zone1, zone2 .. so on are objects of `Zone` 
And if you want to add more camera say for zone1 then you can proceed as follows:

```
ArrayList<Camera> list = map.get(zone1);
list.add(camera3);list.add(camera4);
map.put(zone1,list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a HashMap where the keys are the Zones and the values are a List of the Cameras.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) of `List`s, with the key being `Zone`.

`HashMap<Zone, List<Camera>>`

Answer (score 1):

Why not having a class Zone with number of cameras as a member ?

```
public class Zone {

    private int numOfCameras;

    public Zone(int numOfCameras) {
        this.numOfCameras = numOfCameras;
    }  
}
```

And then you can easily create a list of zones :

```
List<Zone> zonesList = new ArrayList<Zone>();
zoneList.add(new Zone(6);
zoneList.add(new Zone(8);
.
.
```

etc..

I prefer this than a multi list since you can easily add more properties to a zone object and access them from your list.

You can also have a name/id property to a zone object and map zones by id in a map;

Answer (score 1):

Well, one approach would be to use Maps and Lists:

```
HashMap<Zone, ArrayList<Camera>> building = new HashMap<>();

ArrayList<Camera> zone1cameras = new ArrayList<>();
zone1cameras.add(camera1);
zone1cameras.add(camera2);
...

building.put(zone, zone1cameras);
```

But if you already have `Zone` objects, why not something like

```
public class Zone
{
    // Members
    private ArrayList<Camera> cameras = new ArrayList<>();

    // Methods 
    public void registerCamera(Camera c){ cameras.add(c); }
    public List<Camera> getCameras(){ return cameras; }
}
```

And then you could store the `Zone`s in another List, eg:

```
ArrayList<Zone> zones = new ArrayList<>();
zones.add(zone1);
```

If you wanted to get crazy, you could chain the `registerCamera` methods like:

```
public class Zone
{
    // Members
    private ArrayList<Camera> cameras = new ArrayList<>();

    // Methods 
    public Zone registerCamera(Camera c){ cameras.add(c); return this; }
    public List<Camera> getCameras(){ return cameras; }
}
```

Which would allow you to do something like

```
ArrayList<Zone> zones = new ArrayList<>();
zones.add(new Zone().registerCamera(cam1).registerCamera(cam2).registerCamera(cam3));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about create a Zone object (especially helpful if a zone will ever have something else in it). Then in the constructor just pass the number of cameras it has.

```
public class Zone {

    private int numOfCameras;
    private int zoneNumber;

    public Zone(_numOfCameras, _zoneNumber) {
        numOfCameras = _numOfCameras;
        zoneNumber = _zoneNumber;
    }

    //getters and setters
    ...
}
```

If you need to keep a list of zones you can just instantiate an array of zones and add it to the array:

```
private Zone[] zones;
```

To find out how many cameras in a zone you do something like this (this assumes zones will numbered 1-8 in order):

```
public int getNumberOfCamerasByZone(i){ //pass in the zone number you are wanting
    return zones[i].getNumberofCameras();
}
```